# If $X$ is standard normal, how to compute the PDF of $Y=X/(1+ e^{-X})$?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, change-of-variable

If $X \sim N(0,1)$, how can we compute the PDF of $\frac{X}{1+ e^{-X}}$?

I am wondering if there is perhaps an easy way without jacobians. Does anyone have any ideaS?

Comment: It seems that $\frac{X}{1+ e^{-X}}$ is not a one to one function. In this case, how can we determine the Jacobian?

Comment: When $h$ is not one-to-one but regular enough, the PDF $g$ of $Y=h(X)$ is $$g(y)=\sum_{x:h(x)=y}\frac{f_X(x)}{|h'(x)|}$$

Comment: Is the summation above over points of the region where $h$ is one-to-one?

Comment: Huh? The summation is over every $x$ such that $h(x)=y$ (as written in the formula), whether there is a unique such point or several of them.

Comment: @Did is there a link to the above formula and/or more expalantion?